# Post an action on facebook with parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I created an application on facebook with some Open Graph actions. My all actions are approved. Now I have a problem with one of may action. My post url for this action is in format My-App-Namespace:ActionName?ObjectName=MyURL/a/String-Value/_bn/Integer-Value

But when it is posted on FB, one of my parameter "_bn/Integer-Value" is not posted. The post on FB is My-App-Namespace:Action-Name?Object-Name=My-URL/a/String-Value

Is there something I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your code which is writing the meta tags for the object isn't forgetting to include the same parameters in the `og:url` value - this is by far the most likely cause of this problem

Comment: Is parameter order is important.

Comment: No, provided whatever's in your og:url is a valid URL which returns the same tags you should be OK

Comment: I am using the FB PHP Library to post the action. I check my URL using Graph API Explorer and It works fine. But when I post through FB Library method FB->api(URL, 'post', array()); and check the posted action, one parameter _bn is missed. I also check my posted URL it's correct.